# Story ID: the Apollo 11 astronauts return to earth in modern day...

Tags: story-identification, astronauts

I read a synopsis somewhere about a story (maybe a comic) where the Apollo 11 astronauts (Armstrong, Aldrin, etc) return to Earth in modern day without having aged. Questions arise, so who're the real astronauts: these newly returned ones or the ones that have been walking around on Earth the last 50 years?

Anyone hear of it? I've been developing a similar concept but when I read this synopsis I decided to abandon my idea, but now I can't find any evidence of the story and thinking about continuing my project...

Comment: His name was Collins, by the way, not etc.

Comment: Of course. I was using his initials... (Little known fact that the name Micheal actually starts with a silent and invisible 'e'. And his middle name was Trevor...)